# 403 error when posting HTML code as a JSON value

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, netsuite, http-status-code-403

I have an ASP.NET WebAPI endpoint that is accepting a JSON to push to another thirdy party API. I have an issue posting HTML as a JSON value like below:

```
var attr1 = {};
attr1.attributeid = 1234;
attr1.attributevalue = '<div>test</div>';
output.attributes.push(attr1);
```

The result is an HTTP 403 error.

However, when pushing normal strings as JSON, it works, HTTP 200.

```
var attr1 = {};
attr1.attributeid = 1234;
attr1.attributevalue = 'test';
output.attributes.push(attr1);
```

The WebAPI backend is on .NET 4.6.2, requires OAuth 2.0 Bearer tokens with every request. Other things of note, CORS is enabled and the API controller action looks like this:

```
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody] Email email)
        {
            var emailResult = new Email();
            try
            {
                using (var svc = new EmailService())
                {
                    emailResult = await svc.SendTransactionalEmail(email);
                }

                if (emailResult != null)
                {
                    if (emailResult.Success)
                    {
                        return Ok("Transactional email successfully sent!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return BadRequest(emailResult.Result);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return InternalServerError(e);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the forward slash in the attr1.attributevalue like this `'<div>test<\/div>'`

This might help! :)